# Postman and JSON-Data in URL

Tags: api, postman

I use postman for my API-Tests.

within the environments I define a variable `myVariable` and its content is JSON:

`MyVariable` `{ "var1":"value1", "var2":"value2"}`

Can I somehow use this JSON-Values within my request builder in JSON?
[image]

Comment: Are you running into errors or what behavior are you seeing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a bit of work as variables are stored as strings and not object.

Assuming you have set your variable at environment level, in your `Pre-request Script` you need to have the following code:

```
let var1 = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get('myVariable')).var1;
pm.environment.set('var1', var1);
```

And then send your request as:

`http://my-service/index.html?foo={{var1}}`

Comment: Thanks for this hint, I was hoping there would be an easier solution